# iOS 6 EXC_BAD_ACCESS in SampleFTPSample code

Tags: ftp-client, ios6

I run the SampleFTPSample source code (iOS6.0 SDK, Xcode4.5)which downloaded from iOS Developer Center.
[SampleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html)

as the Images, when I retrieved a list from ftpServer, sometimes will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I have not modified the code, I don't know why, and How can I fixed it?

Thank you very much.

[image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Fig.1]
[image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Fig.2]
[image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Fig.3]

Comment: get any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 8):

do this by setting the kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection property to false, immediately after creating the stream (using CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL).  Here's what that might look like:

```
 success = [self.networkStream setProperty:(__bridge id) kCFBooleanFalse
    forKey:(__bridge NSString *) kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection
];
assert(success);
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and why it is necessary?  Is this something new for ios6

Answer (score 1):

yeahh!! I finally got the solution. I invoked uialertview show after main thread gets finish.So that it wont crash now. It is in mine case. So don't have an exact answer but you can also apply this 
peterlawn. May be it will be usefull to you to as well. !!

Comment: Is there any better way of fixing this since I need to do the FTP connection in the background while the user is working with the app and I cannot show an alert in the main thread.

Comment: yes , for this there's no need of any alert. That's why I told in this answer that this is mine case. For you, you can perform your action at which app is crashing, in a different thread than your background thread, & close that new thread immediately after completion of your task

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)_startReceive:(NSString*) urlPath
{
BOOL                success;
NSURL *             url;
CFReadStreamRef     ftpStream;

assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap receive twice in a row!

// First get and check the URL.

if(urlPath != nil)
{
   ...url = FTP_URL here... 
}
success = (url != nil);
// If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.
if ( ! success) 
{
    [self _updateStatus:@"Invalid URL"];
} 
else 
{

    // Create the mutable data into which we will receive the listing.

    self.listData = [NSMutableData data];
    assert(self.listData != nil);

    // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

    ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url);
    assert(ftpStream != NULL);

    self.networkStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *) ftpStream;



    success = [self.networkStream setProperty:(__bridge id) kCFBooleanFalse
    forKey:(__bridge NSString *) kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection
               ];
    assert(success);


    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];

    // Have to release ftpStream to balance out the create.  self.networkStream 
    // has retained this for our persistent use.

    CFRelease(ftpStream);

    // Tell the UI we're receiving.

    [self _receiveDidStart];
}
```

}