# Exc_Bad_Access in alertview show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash, exc-bad-access

Getting Exc_Bad_Access in UIAlertView show message.

```
UIAlertView *systemAlert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"System message" message:@"note" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [systemAlert1 show];  **//Crashing on this line [EXC_BAD_ACCESS]**
    [systemAlert1 release];
```

Why i am getting this?? Please help

Comment: check after enabling zombie mode.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. The problem must be elsewhere. Where do you show your alert? Is it a background thread?

Comment: it is running properly on simulator but crashing on device.

Comment: zombie enabled but it is throwing exc_bad_access

Comment: swatisharma Are you creating the application which is ARC enable?

Comment: ARC is disable. It is running properly in simulator.

Comment: Can you comment [systemAlert1 release]; and check. I checked this code in Simulator and Device it's working on both.

Comment: Because you are showing it in a current running thread. Refer my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578076/ios-6-exc-bad-access-in-sampleftpsample-code/12794543#12794543 Enjoy Programming

Comment: @swatisharma I think what Rushi said is right..

Comment: @swatisharma you skip nil parameter at the end with coma , see my answer..

Comment: need more code to see the whole pic

Comment: Do you have any categories for UIAlertView? Where do you call the alert from? Show us more code, I can't see anything wrong in this code.

Answer (score 1):

ANY UI stuff including the showing of alerts should be done on Main thread.
If you are doing this on some other thread, it will definitely crash.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your alert gets invoked from your background thread and not the main thread. It is recommended that user interface related changes should only be made on Main Thread to avoid this kind of behaviors of the application

Try this code:

```
UIAlertView *systemAlert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"System message" message:@"note" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[systemAlert1 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; 
[systemAlert1 release];
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need anything else.